# Decoding of a encoded base64 string

Tags: python-3.x, base64, decoding

I have a base64 encoded string S="aGVsbG8=", now  i want to decode the string into ASCII, UTF-8, UTF-16, UTF-32, CP-1256, ISO-8659-1, ISO-8659-2, ISO-8659-6, ISO-8659-15 and Windows-1252, How i can decode the string into the mentioned format.  For UTF-16 I tried following code, but it was giving error "'bytes' object has no attribute 'deocde'".
base64.b64decode(encodedBase64String).deocde('utf-8')

Comment: The error gives a hint: `deocde` does not exist. `deocde` should be `decode`

Comment: Plus, that won't give you UTF-16.

Comment: Please make your question more readable by putting the error between backticks `` and mark the code as code using the {} button.  Also correct the spelling error.

Answer (score 0):

Please read the doc or docstring for the 3.x base64 module.  The module works with bytes, not text.  So your base64 encoded 'string' would be a byte string `B = b"aGVsbG8"`.  The result of `base64.decodebytes(B)` is bytes; binary data with whatever encoding it has (text or image or ...).  In this case, it is `b'hello'`, which can be viewed as ascii-encoded text.  To change to other encodings, first decode to unicode text and then encode to bytes in whatever other encoding you want.  Most of the encodings you list above will have the same bytes.

```
>>> B=b"aGVsbG8="
>>> b = base64.decodebytes(B)
>>> b
b'hello'
>>> t = b.decode()
>>> t
'hello'
>>> t.encode('utf-8')
b'hello'
>>> t.encode('utf-16')
b'\xff\xfeh\x00e\x00l\x00l\x00o\x00'
>>> t.encode('utf-32')
b'\xff\xfe\x00\x00h\x00\x00\x00e\x00\x00\x00l\x00\x00\x00l\x00\x00\x00o\x00\x00\x00'
```